# Css animation execution order

Tags: css, css-animations

i'm a beginner in code and i encontered a little problem.

I created a chessboard and i wanted to make animation with the chess pieces.

My problem is, the first animation of the first piece start, then the second piece launch its animation and my problem start here. After the second piece ended its animation, i want to this same piece launch a new animation. But i don't know how to do it. I tried to add it a second class and created a new Keyframe with only this new class, but it failed.

Hope someone will give me the solution :)

```css
table
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:thin;
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
   
    
    
}


td
{
    border-style: solid;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.white
{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.black
{
    background-color: grey;
    
}

img
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
    
}

h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Agency FB;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.l2 img
{
    filter:invert(100%);
}

.validation
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height:500px
}

.move
{
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 2.5s; 
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  100% { left:0px; top:65px;}
}


.move2
{
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example2;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes example2 {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  100% { left:0px; top:-65px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
 <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8" >
        <title>Echequier Version CSS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="echequier.css">
 </head>
 <body>
        
        <h1>Exercice Echéquier Version CSS</h1>

  <table>
      <tr>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="3839.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="44903.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="45124.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="chess.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="games-3355293_960_720.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="3839.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="44903.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="45124.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="chess.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="games-3355293_960_720.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="black l2"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion noir"></td>
                <td class="white l2"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion noir" class="move"></td>
                
            </tr>
            
            
            <tr>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                
            </tr>
            
            
            <tr>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                 <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="white"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="white"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion blanc" class="move2"></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="3839.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="white"><img src="44903.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="45124.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="white"><img src="chess.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="games-3355293_960_720.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="white"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="black"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="white"><img src="3839.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="44903.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="white"><img src="45124.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="chess.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="white"><img src="games-3355293_960_720.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                <td class="white"><img src="32459.png" alt="pion blanc"></td>
                
            </tr>

  </table>

        
    <div>   
        <a href="exercice%20echequier%20feuille%202%20.html">Page de Validation</a>
       </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

PS: I only can use html and CSS. I can't use others language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat your animation :

```
 .move2
{
  position: relative;
  animation:   example2 5s infinite;
}
```

If you whant to start a second animation when the first one ends then you should change your animations delays. Something like:

```
 @keyframes example1 {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  50% { left:0px; top:50px;} 
  100% { left:0px; top:50px;}
}


 @keyframes example2 {
      0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
      50% { left:0px; top:0px;} 
      100% { left:0px; top:-50px;}
    }
```